# Problem with uploading Image with bigger size (Application/octet-stream) - Laravel Media Library

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, mime-types, laravel-medialibrary

I'm using Laravel Media Library by Spatie. 
Works perfectly on Local Machine, but whenever I try to upload an Image with size more than 2MB, it gives me the following error:

```
Spatie \ MediaLibrary \ Exceptions \ FileCannotBeAdded \ FileDoesNotExist
File `/` does not exist
```

I've already done the dd() and image comes with mime-type: **Application/octet-stream**

Whenever the image is with the above mime-type, the error occurs.

PS: I've already checked the similar questions on stackoverflow and already updated the **upload_max_filesize**, but did not work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is a default PHP setting in the `php.ini` file. Check `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: Did you update the correct `php.ini` file. There are sometimes 2 one for Apache/PHP and one for PHP CLI

Comment: Check which file is being used as Apache/PHP ini file using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Only mime type `Application/octet-stream` has the size limitation?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've already done that and I'm using Nginx

Comment: @user3783243 yes, for Application/octet-stream only and don't know why am I getting that mime type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check config/medialibrary.php

'max_file_size' => 1024 * 1024 * 10 // For 10MB